# Java bug extends

Tags: java

I'm making a game in Java SE 8. I have to add a class in `extends` but there is already one added, and I cannot remove it. I would just like to know how to put 2 classes in `extends`.

Comment: You cannot extend more than one class. With Java 8 though, you can add `default` methods to interfaces and possibly get to the same thing by implementing multiple interfaces.

Comment: Java does not allow this. You need to find another way.

Comment: You should paste your code. You will get the right suggestions that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not extends 2 classes in java. java doesn't support multiple inheritance. you can make it like if you have 3 classes A, B, C than A extends B and B extends C.

Answer (score 0):

Extends models inheritance. In Java there is only "single inheritance", in other words: you can only have a single super class to extend from (which itself can only extend from one super class, and so on). You can have multiple interfaces, and since Java 8 interfaces can also have *some* implementation, but it's a controversial subject, maybe just a loophole. Most of the time, your desire for multiple inheritance can be solved by a better design of your class. Maybe your class is trying to do too many things (too many responsibilities), and you can split it up. Maybe you can use composition (using delegate classes, either via fields on *your* class, or by calling into static methods on utility classes), instead of inheritance.